# How do you calculate expanding mean on time series using pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, time-series

How would you create a column(s) in the below pandas DataFrame where the new columns are the expanding mean/median of 'val' for each 'Mod_ID_x'.  Imagine this as if were time series data and 'ID' 1-2 was on Day 1 and 'ID' 3-4 was on Day 2.

I have tried every way I could think of but just can't seem to get it right.

```
left4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],'val': [10000, 25000, 20000, 40000],
'Mod_ID': [15, 35, 15, 42],'car': ['ford','honda', 'ford', 'lexus']})    


right4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [3,1,2,4],'color': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'grey'], 'wheel': ['4wheel','4wheel', '2wheel', '2wheel'], 
                      'Mod_ID': [15, 15, 35, 42]})

df1 = pd.merge(left4, right4, on='ID').drop('Mod_ID_y', axis=1)
```

[image: Pandas DataFrame]

Answer (score 2):

Hard to test properly on your DataFrame, but you can use something like this:

```
>>> df1["exp_mean"] = df1[["Mod_ID_x","val"]].groupby("Mod_ID_x").transform(pd.expanding_mean)
>>> df1
   ID  Mod_ID_x    car    val  color   wheel  exp_mean
0   1        15   ford  10000  green  4wheel     10000
1   2        35  honda  25000   blue  2wheel     25000
2   3        15   ford  20000    red  4wheel     15000
3   4        42  lexus  40000   grey  2wheel     40000
```